# Can a process have multiple parents? why or why not?

Tags: process, child-process

I know a parent process can have multiple children. But can a child have multiple parents? why or why not?

Comment: No, not at any one given time. But a process can be re-parented.

Comment: I went ahead and removed both of your unrelated / overgeneralized tags and tried to find better ones. Please don't use tags that you don't explicitly mention in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

> can a child have multiple parents?

No. By definition of what we understand as parent process, it's the process that spawned the child process. **One process** has to do that. And that's the parent.

> why or why not?

Because that's how we define the parent-child relationship.

Comment: But when original parent dies, [Orphan process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) will be adopted (re-parented) by pid 1. So at any point of time there is only one parent, but in some cases parent can be changed.

Comment: @osgx no doubt about that!